# How to access `ScriptEngine.Sys` in IronPython 2?

Tags: ironpython

I'm trying to add some variables to `sys.argv` when hosting a script in IronPython 2. The internet is being all 1990 on me, showing [how to do it in IronPython 1](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/custom_executable.shtml):

```
engine.Sys.argv = List.Make(args);
```

Except, well, `ScriptEngine` no longer has a `Sys` member...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point we added scriptEngine.GetSysModule() which is an extension method on the ScriptEngine class.  It's in the IronPython.Hosting namespace in the Python class.  That returns a ScriptScope which you can fetch the argv member from.

If you're really using 2.0 I'm not sure if it's there or not though.

Comment: What if I want to set argv e.g. if I want to pass the command line arguments from C# to IronPython?